# python writing txt file 500* 36 zero,then wrap lines in every 16

Tags: python, loops, wrapper

I would like to write a txt file like this ,

```
TIME           =            0.00 hours since 1999-06-30 14:00:00 +00:00
x_spw_eye      =     138.50
y_spw_eye      =       7.20
pdrop_spw_eye =         1000.00
     0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
     0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
     0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
```

there is 16 column in every first two lines , then every 4 column in the third line,all in all , the total three lines will loop in 1500 times

I create a loop like this,

```
print ('TIME           =            0.00 hours since 1999-06-30 14:00:00 +00:00')
print ('x_spw_eye      =     138.50')
print ('y_spw_eye      =       7.20')
print ('pdrop_spw_eye =         1000.00')

for i in range(0,500):
    for j in range (0,16):
        print '%8.1f' % (0),
    print
```

but it just showed the 16 column without the 4 columns, no idea how.

Is there anyone has any idea?

BTW, the float format of zero should be '%8.1f'

Thank you so much!!!!

All the bests,
Li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are shorter ways to accomplish what you want. However, most simply perhaps you can simply repeat 3 loops 500 times

```
for i in range(500):
    for j in range (16):
        print '%8.1f' % (0),
    print 
    for j in range (16):
        print '%8.1f' % (0),
    print
    for j in range (4):
        print '%8.1f' % (0),
    print
```

One more compact way is

```
for i in range(500):
    print " ".join('%8.1f' % 0 for j in range(16))
    print " ".join('%8.1f' % 0 for j in range(16))
    print " ".join('%8.1f' % 0 for j in range(4))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!could I add one question, how could I write alles in a txt file? I did like thisf = open ('test_1.txt','w')
f.write('TIME           =            0.00 hours since 1999-06-30 14:00:00 +00:00\n')
f.write('x_spw_eye      =     138.50\n')
f.write('y_spw_eye      =       7.20\n')
f.write('pdrop_spw_eye =         1000.00\n')
for i in range(500):
    for j in range (16):
        print '%8.1f' % (0),
    print 
    for j in range (16):
        print '%8.1f' % (0),
    print
    for j in range (4):
        print '%8.1f' % (0),
    print 
fout.close(), but the values parts missing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, based on your answers, I finished alles scripts.